# How do I scale my axis appropriately when using a D3JS Axis + viewbox?

Tags: d3.js, axis, viewbox

I'm attempting to plot a graph using d3js.  I wanted to keep everything proportional, so I have been using the 'viewBox' attribute on my svg element, like this:

```
svg.attr("viewBox", "-5 -5 10 10")
```

Everything worked great until I tried to add an axis.  When I add an axis, the scale is completely messed up and looks wrong.  I've simplified it down to this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gq6tykwL/5/

The axis just displays as a giant black bar, and if you inspect those html elements you will see that they are tick marks that are huge..

If I change my viewbox to mirror the width/height of the svg, like this:

```
svg.attr("viewBox", "0 0 500 500")
```

Then the axis appears as I would expect, however my graph won't draw at the appropriate scale any longer.  Jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rdua3ncp/

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?  Or should I just take another approach on the axis?

Comment: Viewbox defines boundary in SVG units. What you did was shoving an axis into 10x10 square, and then stretch that square to fit html size of the svg element

Comment: I'm not sure in what way you mean "proportional", but I don't think I would be using a viewbox at all; instead listen for svg size changes, and rerender as needed with the new size